# Vim in Iterm2 closes after compiling Latex file

Tags: iterm, vi, latex, macvim

When I run

```
!pdflatex %
```

in Macvim, the latex file compiles and I am not exited from Macvim. In iterm2, the compilation occurs and them I am taken out of Vim back into the terminal prompt. Any ideas why the behavior is different? I have looked around and to my surprise haven't seen anything about it.